# Is there a way to "fetch" the "installation source" of an installed eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I just installed a new Ubuntu; and also decided to do a complete refresh of my eclipse workspace. But now I am facing an issue with an internal eclipse update site that I used in the past to install some internal plugin ...

Long story short: I can't provide an "install site" to eclipse for a plugin I would like to install.

Now I am wondering:

I did install this plugin earlier on (and I still have that **system image** and workspace around); so is there a way to "pull" the "plugin install artifacts" from an workspace it was installed to? And then use those artifacts to install the plugin without having an "install site"?

Comment: Plugins are in the Eclipse install directory not the workspace. Do  you have the old Eclipse install?

Comment: Yes. Highlighted that in the question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the old plugin in the 'plugins' directory of the old Eclipse installation. You should just be able to copy the plugin to the 'dropins' directory of the new Eclipse and restart Eclipse to get it installed.

Comment: If 'dropins" directory mean to simply copy eclipse-old/plugins/the.jar to eclipse-new/plugins/the.jar ... well, then doing that resolved my problem ;-)

Comment: Well there should be an actual directory called 'dropins' although not all installs seem to create it. Just copying to the 'plugins' directory does often work but isn't officially recommended.